# How to generate html code to pdf file and send it to mail using php

Tags: php

I want to generate HTML code to pdf file and need to send it to mail.I am new to this.
Please any one can help me with simple code how to generate pdf file and send it to mail using PHP.

Thanks,
Dhamodhar

Comment: Have a look at these http://www.fpdf.org/ and http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Get [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.com) Libraries from this site.  After including the libraries make use of this code

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 049');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 049', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

]$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();


$html = '<h1>Test TCPDF Methods in HTML</h1>
<h2 style="color:red;">IMPORTANT:</h2>
<span style="color:red;">If you are using user-generated content, the tcpdf tag can be unsafe.<br />
You can disable this tag by setting to false the <b>K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML</b> constant on TCPDF configuration file.</span>
<h2>write1DBarcode method in HTML</h2>';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 39', 'C39', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 128', 'C128', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';

$html .= '<tcpdf method="AddPage" /><h2>Graphic Functions</h2>';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(0));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="SetDrawColor" params="'.$params.'" />';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(50, 50, 40, 10, 'DF', array(), array(0,128,255)));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="Rect" params="'.$params.'" />';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example_049.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Access this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm) to check out how to send mails in PHP.